# Prémonition propice?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Quand une personne dit qu'elle avait la prémonition que quelque chose allait se produire, veut-elle impliquer qu'elle regarde cette chose comme indésirable ?

Par exemple, est-ce que la citation qui suit paraît bizarre ?

- J'ai fait le rêve qu'on avait enfin retrouvé mon portefeuille disparu. Ouf ! J'espère que c'est une prémonition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non, une prémonition ne présume pas du côté positif ou négatif de ce qui est pressenti.

La phrase est donc possible. On peut aussi utiliser l'adjectif un peu plus courant *prémonitoire*:

> J'espère que c'est prémonitoire.

J'éviterais le *ouf* car on ne sait pas encore si la prémonition va se réaliser.